# How to query and update nested JSON data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-jsonfield, jsonfield

I have below class defined to do statistics for voting system.

```
class FormPage(AbstractForm):
    submission_stats = models.JSONField(null=True, editable=False)
```

Now, I have `submission_stats` in below format:

```
[
   {
      "id":4,
      "label":"checkboxes",
      "choices":[
         {
            "content":"option-A",
            "num_vote":0,
            "user_list":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "content":"option-B",
            "num_vote":0,
            "user_list":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "content":"option-C",
            "num_vote":0,
            "user_list":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "label":"Radio Button",
      "choices":[
         {
            "content":"option-1",
            "num_vote":0,
            "user_list":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "content":"option-2",
            "num_vote":0,
            "user_list":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "content":"option-3",
            "num_vote":0,
            "user_list":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

When I receive 2 vote submissions for example, I want to update `num_vote` (from 0 to 2) and `user_list` (from `[]` to `[user_a, user_b]`) field in this JSONField accordingly.

**How to query and update elements in nested JSONField data please ?**

Comment: Why you have `mdels.JsonField` in form ? And where do you want to update the values ?

Comment: updated the post to reflect where I want to update the values. this `models.JsonField` attribute in the `form` is for statistics of form submission results. For example, how many users voted for option-A, and who are those users.

Answer (score 0):

install json library
pip install json

```
import json

data = json.load(submission_stats)
```

now this data is python dictionary. update it however you want

to save updated data back to json field, convert dictionary back to json like this

```
json.dumps(data, indent = 4)
```

and save

plus if you want to use sql with your this project i highly recomment you use

```
from django_extensions.db.fields.json import  JSONField
```

instead of

```
models.JSONField
```

because models.JSONField doesn't go well with SQL

Comment: `json.load(submission_stats)` gives me error: **`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'`** as my `submission_stats` is a `List` not `Dictionary`. Is changing to `Dictionary` the only way to go ?

Comment: oops. sorry didn't notice that it was list. try json.load(submission_stats[0]). yeah it the most feasible and logical way to go. then you can retrieve value by keys and update them easily